# ajax, php and twitter's bootstrap typeahead

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

Alright so I am trying to populate the typeahead of twitter's bootstrap and I followed this answer:
[Twitter bootstrap Typeahead to populate hrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957152/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-to-populate-hrefs)

But I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined edit-group?id=14:239
>   $.typeahead.matcher edit-group?id=14:239

Here is the code for it:

```
matcher: function (obj) {
    var item = JSON.parse(obj);
    return ~item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())
},
```

I looked into the network tab to see if get the correct data and I get this:

```
0: {title:The1Prodigy1, href:1}
href: 1
title: "The1Prodigy1"
1: {title:test_suspend_user, href:4}
href: 4
title: "test_suspend_user"
    2: {title:test_ban_user, href:5}
3: {title:test_delete_user, href:6}
4: {title:user_test_edit, href:7}
```

One last question, do I need the href? Because, all I want to do is help the user type the correct username. I don't want it to be linked to another page or anything. It is for a form...

EDIT:
I added an alert of item.title and it sends back undefined... Why is that?

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: `return ~item.title.toLowerCase()...` so `~item` is typo?

Comment: I took away the ~, but it sends the same error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items in your Typeahead `source` are objects, you are going to have to jump through some hoops. Otherwise, you will get that error as Bootstrap Typeahead tries to internally call `toLowerCase()` to compare items, sort items, etc.

I published a blog post not long ago on how to do this: http://victorblog.com/2013/06/21/how-to-use-rich-objects-and-typed-objects-with-bootstrap-typeahead/

I am sure you simply haven't overridden the `updater` function for Typeahead.

Comment: I am not too sure to understand what you mean... I took out matcher, sorter and highligher and the typeahead is working. But it shows the whole array... <a href="#">{"href":1,"name":"<strong>The</strong>1Prodigy1"}</a>

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out!

Comment: Can you share exactly what you needed to add or change to make it work? :)